# Installing GWT plugin in Chrome

Tags: gwt, google-chrome

It worked like this: after opening a link with a `?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997` after a suggestion GWT plugin was downloaded and installed. But I've just got this message: `Extensions, apps, and user scripts can only be added from the Chrome Web Store`. And I couldn't find it in the store. So, what is a way to install it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to chrome://chrome/extensions in your browser and drag and drop the file you downloaded (should be named google-dev-pluggin.crx I think)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Still, it's a bit strange that it worked, because, well, it was not the "install from the market" option.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to install the plugin is, to load the google chrome Browser with the 
flag `–enable-easy-off-store-extension-install`
With this flag you disable this "feature".

For more informations, see [here](http://techie-buzz.com/browsers/chrome-blocking-extension-apps-scripts-chrome-web-store.html)

Answer (score 1):

Chrome 21 changed the policy on installing extension to chrome to "only from chrome web store".

This is already addressed in the GWT contributer group and will be fixed within a week or two.

See discussion (with workaround) from the contributer list: https://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit-contributors/browse_thread/thread/24eaf2956ca4a212#