# Where can I find GWT developer plugin for Chrome on Windows?

Tags: gwt, chrome-web-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing GWT plugin in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901915/installing-gwt-plugin-in-chrome)

I am unable to test my GWT project fast enough without it. And I can't find this plugin at the Chrome web store. Although I could download the plugin, Chrome says it won't deploy a plugin unless downloaded directly from the Chrome web store. Anybody know a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to bypass the Chrome store check:

1) Type "chrome://extensions" in the browser address bar to open the Extensions screen, then drag and drop the ".crx" extension file on that window.

2) Launch Chrome from the command-line with the switch "--enable-easy-off-store-extension-install"